# Count down timer causing unexpected close in android game application

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to add a countdown timer to my rendering class, however, when I add the startTimer function and run the game, the game closes and says an unexpected error occurred. I have omitted a large amount of code from this class due to the fact that I have allocated the problem to the timer function.

```
public class GRenderer implements Renderer 
{
    // I have omitted a lot of irrelevant code for this question 

    public void startTimer ()
    {

        new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
             {

             }

             public void onFinish() 
             {
                 Toast.makeText(Game.context, "TIMER ENDED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 // put score into DB
                 // load a different screen
             }
          }.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) // when drawing to screen
    {
        // Omitted functions
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) 
    {
        // Omitted functions
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) 
    {
        startTimer();
        // Omitted functions
    }

}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
12-10 16:41:45.796: E/AndroidRuntime(5336): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 284 12-10 16:41:45.796: E/AndroidRuntime(5336): Process: com.damienrenner.spacefruitshooter, PID: 5336

12-10 16:41:45.796: E/AndroidRuntime(5336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

12-10 16:41:45.796: E/AndroidRuntime(5336): at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:200)

12-10 16:41:45.796: E/AndroidRuntime(5336): at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:114)

12-10 16:41:45.796: E/AndroidRuntime(5336): at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.(CountDownTimer.java:109)

12-10 16:41:45.796: E/AndroidRuntime(5336): at android.os.CountDownTimer.(CountDownTimer.java:109)

12-10 16:41:45.796: E/AndroidRuntime(5336): at com.damienrenner.spacefruitshooter.GRenderer$1.(GRenderer.java:274)

12-10 16:41:45.796: E/AndroidRuntime(5336): at com.damienrenner.spacefruitshooter.GRenderer.startTimer(GRenderer.java:274)

12-10 16:41:45.796: E/AndroidRuntime(5336): at com.damienrenner.spacefruitshooter.GRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(GRenderer.java:331)

12-10 16:41:45.796: E/AndroidRuntime(5336): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1501)

12-10 16:41:45.796: E/AndroidRuntime(5336): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Comment: paste your logcat stack trace.

Comment: I have just added the logcat

Answer (score 1):

You're calling it from a worker thread. You could use a handler, or run your code like :-

here are following ways you can use to solve it:-

runOnUiThread

```
new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        myactivity.this.runOnUiThread(new runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                //Do your UI operations like dialog opening or Toast here
            }
        });
    }
}.start();
```

LOOPER

```
class LooperThread extends Thread {
    public Handler mHandler;

    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

        mHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // process incoming messages here
            }
        };

        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

AsyncTask

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new CustomTask().execute((Void[])null);
}


private class CustomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... param) {
        //Do some work
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
        //Print Toast or open dialog
    }
}
```

Handler

```
    Message msg = new Message();


    new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            msg.arg1=1;
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }.start();


Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.arg1==1)
        {
            //Print Toast or open dialog        
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have adapted my code to the code you provided ... however, I get the following error : Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method runOnUiThread(Runnable) from the type Activity

Comment: I update my answer with number of ways to solve this kind of issue, you can use any of one form it.

Comment: runOnUiThread is not a static method. so get instance of your activity and use it.

Comment: Im trying to implement the first solution, however, I am getting an error on runOnUiThread saying I need to create a method called runOnUiThread.

Comment: I am calling it like this: GRenderer.this.runOnUiThread(new runnable() ..... GRenderer is the class it is contained in

Comment: No, you must use an activity instance, as GRenderer is not an activity

Comment: Sorry, I have now changed it to Game.this.runOnUiThread (Game is the activity) ... however, I am getting the following error : No enclosing instance of the type Game is accessible in scope

Comment: you need to pass activty instance to GRenderer class. its depend how you are access GRenderer class from your activity.